# Java while function not running

Tags: java

```
        while (done = false)
        {
        if (((int1 / int2) >= 1.0) && ((int1 / int3) >= 1.0))
        {
            System.out.println(outputInt1 + " ");
            int1 = 0.1;
        }
        if (((int2 / int1) >= 1.0) && ((int2 / int3) >= 1.0))
        {
            System.out.println(outputInt2 + " ");
            int2 = 0.1;
        }
        if (((int3 / int1) >= 1.0) && ((int3 / int2) >= 1.0))
        {
            System.out.println(outputInt3 + " ");
            int3 = 0.1;
        }
        else if ((int1 == 0.1) && (int2 == 0.1) && (int3 == 0.1))
        {
            done = true;
        }
        }
```

Hi, I can't seem to be able to figure out why this while statement will not run. In the console it simply will not print anything in the if statements.

I assume it's an error with my arithmetic in the if condition.

Thanks!

Comment: `(done = false)` assigns false to `done` and evaluates to false, so your `while` loop immediacy finishes.

Comment: If these values are actually of type `int`, then I hope you're not expecting them ever to be equal to `0.1`.

Comment: `while` is a statement, not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to `while(done == false)`. :) Or, even better, `while(!done)`. What `while(done = false)` does is the following:

1. First, set `done` to `false`
2. Evaluate `done` to check if the while loop should execute.
3. See that `done` is `false`, so don't execute.

Comment: It evaluates the result of the assignment expression. Assignment returns a value. So, `done = false` will set `done` to `false`, and return the new value of `done`, which is `false`. In that sense, it won't re-evaluate `done`, it'll just return the value of `done` *if* you were to re-evaluate it.

Comment: completely missed that, thanks!